# When do Efficient Decision Algorithms for 1D Anomaly Detection exist (compared to threshold-tests)?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, anomaly-detection, threshold

I'm tasked with investigating whether machine learning algorithms can be used to efficiently identify if a certain type of anomaly is present in the temporal spacing of incoming network packets. Identifying the anomaly using threshold tests takes a fairly long time, since it is pretty small. However my initial experiments with ML-algorithms didn't show a lot of promise in reducing this detection time, so I'm trying to mathematically determine wether ML would even garner a significant performance increase.

The problem can be modeled as follows:

> Let R and c be random variables from $\mathbb{R}^+$  with known probability distributions
> and c << R. Of a third random variable X it is known that either X = R
> or X = R + c.
>
> How many times does X need to be measured to determine
> within reasonable certainty whether X = R or X = R + c?
> Under which
> circumstances do decision algorithms with higher efficiency than
> simple threshold-tests exist?

The second question is the important one.

This sounds like the kind of problem where a lot of research in its general direction has already been done. Could you give me some recommended reading or refer me to theorems that deal with this type of problem?

My mathematical intuition would suggest that if R and c are normal, threshold-tests are always the most efficient decision algorithms. However it is also fairly easy to come up with situations where this isn't the case (e.g. if the probability density of R has sharp peaks, detecting their movement could be done with higher precision than for the whole of R)

Comment: Need more information about the 'certain type' of temporal anomaly in order to even understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Carl Isn't the explicit model good enough?

Comment: @whuber Yes, it is, but only if it is relevant, and we don't know that, do we?

Comment: @Carl Unless you see some kind of contradiction or inconsistency in the question, it is not constructive (and, imho, disrespectful) to suppose that a key clarifying passage might be irrelevant.

Comment: @whuber The intro says "if a certain type of anomaly is present in the temporal spacing of incoming network packets." I do not think that an inability to detect something is the same thing as its not being present; that goes to the sensitivity of detection which is not absolute. What the detection limits are, is central to the need for clarification, and opened up multiple hypothetical other questions for me. For example, "What happens to detectability if c is not perfectly constant?"

Comment: @Carl I wonder how you get from "temporal spacing" to discussing detection limits.  There's no apparent connection.

Comment: The concrete problem is as follows: 
I'm doing a project as part of larger research about a network covert channel which operates by recalculating hashes and is practically only detectable by the packet delay it causes. My colleagues have used standard statistical approaches and are able to detect it somewhat reliably. But their approach needs a lot of measurements to achieve a reasonable level of certainty. I've been tasked with determining wether or not the detection can be sped up by ML.

Comment: In this context R is the routing time and c is the covert channel delay. They can be assumed to be independent random variables, as the decoding of the hash and its recalculation (which are not dependent on the variables influencing routing time) constitute most of c.

Comment: @whuber Can you answer the OP's question? For Jeff S: I am still not understanding everything. One ML approach might be to DNS map server nodes with their corresponding delay times to identify how exactly the traffic got to you.

Comment: @Carl If I have understood correctly, this is a test with a two-element hypothesis space, $R$ and $R+c.$  One would automatically conduct a likelihood ratio test.  For many reasonable distributions it would be a threshold test, but it's not hard to construct some examples where the test is more complicated than that.  Alternatively, if a loss function can be formulated, that ought to lead in a straightforward way to an optimal test.  Given a test, one can then compute the sample size needed to achieve a desired performance.  I'm just reciting standard statistical decision theory.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for that clarification of the traditional approach, but Jeff's question appears to be if a machine learning approach can be used to get an answer faster than 'a fairly long time', which I take to mean that it would be nicer to avoid having to obtain lots of data for a traditional approach.

Comment: @whuber Your answer is somewhat helpful. I am studying applied computer science and am therefore not that deep in the statistical theory (although most of the concepts you've mentioned are known to me). My initial guess was that a somewhat well-known theorem in advanced decision theory would exist that could be applied directly to my problem. By the responses I've gotten this seems not to be the case.

Comment: This is a basic textbook problem, as far as I can tell: it's the very simplest example of a statistical decision problem because it involves a binary choice.   If you're looking for readings, a good textbook account of statistical decision theory would work well.  (I like [Jack Karl Kiefer's book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Statistical-Inference-Springer-Statistics/dp/1461395801).)  If you're looking for an answer, then providing the details of $R$ and $c$ would help.

Comment: @whuber The task I've been given for the project and a following thesis is to either find a ML approach to speed up the detection of the covert channel from the measured delay or present a reasonable argument why no such approach exists. Currently my main focus is compiling research and making a project roadmap so the reading recommendation is probably satisfactory for now.

Comment: As for the details of R and c: R is arbitrary network traffic, determining its characteristics will be part of my thesis' literature review, determining c will be part of the project, but it seems to be almost normal

Comment: Okay, it's good to know what stage you're at, so we don't ask you for information you don't have.  Am I correct in thinking of your problem, though, as concerning just two distributions having the distributions of $R$ and $R+c$?

Comment: What does the routing time R and covert channel delay c depend on (if anything)? If it is dependent on anything in the network traffic, then that information will be highly useful. It may be possible to exploit that in a passive/discriminative way (using a ML classifier), or adversarial way (constructing traffic that maximizes the ease of detecting the covert channel case)